# Smart way to handle nested flux operations

Tags: java, reactor

I have 2 query methods (findByName/findAnotherName) .

Both of them return Mono<List> .

I do some logic by compare results of these two methods, and then return one of them in a nested Flux operation.

It may have a smart way to achieve same result though.

Following is code snippet:

```
private Mono<List<Student>> find(String name) {

    return repo.findByName(name)
            .flatMap((List<Student> students) -> {

                return repo.findAnotherName(anothName, 1).collectList()
                        .flatMap((List<Student> anotherStudents) -> {

                            //do some logic

                            return Mono.just(students);
                        });

            });

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does findAnotherName  depend on the result of findByName?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the result of findByName . 

According to the result , handle business logic , then return a Mono of computed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWhen-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BiFunction-

If your `//do some logic` is sync then I can suggest something like

```
private Mono<List<Student>> find(String name) {

    return repo.findByName(name)
            .zipWhen((List<Student> students) -> {
                return repo.findAnotherName(anothName, 1).collectList();
            }, (students, anotherStudents) -> {
                //some sync logic
                return students;
            });
}
```

But if the logic is also async, then

```
private Mono<List<Student>> find(String name) {

    return repo.findByName(name)
            .zipWhen((List<Student> students) -> {
                return repo.findAnotherName(anothName, 1).collectList()
                        .flatMap(anotherStudents -> someAsyncMethod(anotherStudents));
            }, ((students, o) -> students));
}
```